# Why do bootstrap dropdowns only work when bootstrap-responsive.css is also included?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For a test case, I created a test project with the exact same code from [Hero Demo](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html) and then removed the responsive CSS code.

Why is it that dropdowns do not work unless responsive is also included? I do not wish to use responsive in my project.

Comment: I suspect you've got something else going wrong. [Here's a very basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/CvnFy/) (markup copied directly from the linked demo) using just `bootstrap-dropdown.js` and `bootstrap.css`.

Comment: oh, also using jQuery. The dropdown script relies on jQuery! Make sure you've loaded `jquery.js` and `bootstrap-dropdown.js` before calling `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()​`

Comment: @refhat The point is that it provides a very nice framework for grids, typography, forms, etc. Marked as unconstructive.

Comment: @crowjonah your comment was most useful, obviously the markup provided in the demo is somehow only compatible with responsive, because your markup worked correctly. Add an answer so that I can choose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be something else wrong in your usage. Here's a [very basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/CvnFy/) (markup copied directly from the linked demo) using just `jquery.js`, `bootstrap-dropdown.js`, `bootstrap.css`.

Make sure you've loaded the scripts before calling `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();`, and that you're using the proper selector according to the way you've structured your dropdown!

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate your advice. Also, it's not necessary to include that particular snippet inside of my HTML, as long as the scripts have been included properly.

Answer (score 0):

As @crowjonah mentions in a comment above, dropdowns are not dependent on `responsive.css`. You should verify that you have `jquery.js` included in your page before `bootstrap.js`. I have a page that is not including bootstrap-responsive.css and the dropdowns work just fine. Also you should not need to include `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` if you are using the correct `css` tags as described in the demo. The only features that are opt-in are the tooltips and popovers.

Hope this helps, but if not please update your question with more code example of how you have bootstrap implemented.

Comment: JQuery was included, it was something to do with the markup copied from the demo. Using the markup provided by @crowjonah, it works as expected.